# Entering variables in res.write()

Tags: javascript, html

```html
         Object.keys(result).forEach(function(key) {
            var row = result[key];
            var firstName=row.fname;
            var lastName=row.lname;
            var bloodGroup=row.bloodgroup;
            var state=row.state;
            var city=row.city;
            var address=row.address;
            var pincode=row.pincode;
            var job=row.job;
            var occupation=row.occupation;
          });
        };
     });
     res.write("<!DOCTYPE HTML><html><head>'city'</head></html>");
```

So I want to insert any variable inside this html code in the res.write(), whats the right way to do it?

Comment: With a [template](https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/nodejs/template-engines-for-nodejs)? That's what they're made for.

Answer (score 1):

```
res.write("<!DOCTYPE HTML><html><head>"+city+"</head></html>");
```